# OpenStack Cinder Configuration for separate Storage network

Tags: openstack, cinder

I have OpenStack block storage running using LVMVolumeDriver.

I want to use a dedicated network (10Ge) for storage, but the iSCSI connections are always established through the management address.

I found an old question for the same problem (https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/90405/separate-cinder-storage-traffic-from-management/), but the linked answer doesn't exist anymore.

On the storage node I configured in /etc/cinder/cinder.conf:

```
[DEFAULT]
...
my_ip = 10.48.21.93               ## address in management network
target_ip_address=192.168.100.1   ## address in storage network
...
[lvm]
..
iscsi_ip_address=192.168.100.1
```

When I check the iSCSI connection I see:

```
# tgtadm --mode target --op show
Target 1: iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-b432ec39-ebd0-44fd-a9e7-aa5abf66ae69
    System information:
        Driver: iscsi
        State: ready
    I_T nexus information:
        I_T nexus: 2
            Initiator: (hidden)
            Connection: 0
                IP Address: 10.48.22.48
...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: the LVM cinder driver is a simple proof of concept, if you have a 10GB network and production grade storage hardware you would do much better to deploy Ceph etc. I assume that the iscsi target must resolve back to the host running the LVM service